# How do I fetch the 'x-tracking-id' request header value using Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to fetch the 'x-tracking-id' value as it's shown in Chrome dev tools to replicate a request is there a possible way to do so using python?

[Example image from google chrome's dev tools.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH3v1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x-tracking-id is a custom header from the website, and thus has no standard for how it is handled (unlike a origin or referrer header). There is always a way to replicate it, but are often made difficult with cryptography or encryption for the sole purpose of preventing reverse engineering. A few suggestions despite this are googling the website or header to see if someone has already made progress reverse engineering, looking at the page source and CTRL + F to search for it, using CTRL+ F in chrome dev tools to find it in another request being produced, or trying to look in the JavaScript code to see where the header is made (but often this is the most difficult since the JavaScript is obfuscated).